# Not able to use SynchronizeWithSchemaAndUpdate or SynchronizeWithSchema for Structure Group

Tags: 2013, core-service

Using coreservice 7.1 When i try to synchronize a Component or a Page using `SynchronizeWithSchemaAndUpdate` method it synchronizes successfully, but when ever i try to synchronize a Structure Group it gives an error:

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message:
>
> There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
>   http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2013:SynchronizeWithSchemaAndUpdateResult.
>   The InnerException message was 'Invalid enum value
>   'BusinessProcessTypeManagement' cannot be deserialized into type
>   'Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.Rights'. Ensure that the
>   necessary enum values are present and are marked with
>   EnumMemberAttribute attribute if the type has DataContractAttribute
>   attribute.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rights.BusinessProcessTypeManagement enum value was introduced in Web 8. So I assume you're trying to run your code against Web 8 or newer using the Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.dll version 7.1.

In general, CM tries to adjust data model to the client version as much as possible. Specifically, it nullifies properties unknown to client. However, it cannot do anything with enum values. Try to update your project to use CoreService.Client of the version matching with the CM you're connecting to (e.g. 8.0).